# Память при создании переменной типа class

Tags: c++, память

Когда мы создаем переменную `int var = 5`, все понятно, компьютер берет (выделяет) память 32 бита и записывает туда значение `5` в двоичном виде.

Но что происходит когда мы создаем переменную типа класс? `class a = 5`. Что происходит? Сколько байт выделяется под эту переменную?

Comment: В первом случае ничего не понятно, так как размер типа `int` и количество реально выделяемой под него памяти определяется компилятором. Во втором случае ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: `class a = 5` - такого в С++ не бывает. `class` - это ключевое слово и оно не может быть использовано таким образом .

Comment: @VTT почему пишут такое? "myVar1 = 25; Указывает компьютеру, что нужно выделить память для переменной myVar1 типа int. Размер памяти выделяемой для нее зависит от самого компьютера. Например на 32-х разрядном компьютере он равен 4 байтам(32 бит)."

Comment: `myVar1 = 25;` можно написать только для уже ранее объявленной переменной. Поэтому не не ясно о каком "указывает компьютеру, что нужно выделить память" вы ведете речь. Нет, ничего подобного это не указывает.

Comment: При создании экземпляра класса автоматически запускается конструктор, который может делать с памятью что угодно, хоть всю память зарезервировать.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Речь, по видимому, идет о памяти, занимаемой самим объектом класс-типа. К моменту запуска конструктора память для этого объекта уже выделена и меняться не может.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Объект в стеке

В программе выделяется столько байт, сколько требуется для хранения данных экземпляра данного класса. Например, объект пустого класс займёт один байт, если в нём хранится `int`, то его размер прибавится к размеру объекта класса. Вот интересный код для исследования этих свойств:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class EmptyClass
{    
};

class AbstractClass
{
  public: 
          virtual void funcOne() = 0;
          virtual void funcTwo() = 0;
};

class NotAbstrClass
{
  public: int virtFunc( int );
};

class VarClass
{
  public:
          static int i;
          int j, k;
};

int main()
{
    // Вывод размера экземпляров классов

    // Размер класса равен размеру экземпляра класса
    EmptyClass e = EmptyClass();
    cout<<"Size of empty class: "<< sizeof(e)<<endl;          
    cout<<"Size of Abstract class: "<< sizeof(AbstractClass)<<endl;
    cout<<"Size of Non Abstract class: "<< sizeof(NotAbstrClass)<<endl;
    cout<<"Size of Var class: "<< sizeof(VarClass)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат выполнения с моим компилятором:

```
Size of Empty class: 1
Size of Abstract class: 8
Size of Non Abstract class: 1
Size of Var class: 8
```

Меняя число переменных можно заметить, что поля с модификатором `static` не влияют на размер выделенной памяти, что и логично, ведь она не относится к конкретным экземплярам класса.

---

### Объект в куче

При динамическом создании объекта, то есть, выделении памяти в куче, помимо размера самого экземпляра класса можно учесть также и размер указателя на него:

```
EmptyClass *v = new EmptyClass();
cout<<"Size of pointer: "<< sizeof(v)<<endl;
cout<<"Size of object: "<< sizeof(*v)<<endl;
```

Получается даже, что размер указателя может быть больше самого объекта:

```
Size of pointer: 8
Size of object: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае - `int var = 5;` - компилятор выделяет `sizeof(int)` байтов памяти под переменную `var`. Это совсем не обязательно 32 бита.

Во втором случае - `Class a = 5;` - компилятор точно таким же образом выделяет `sizeof(Class)` байтов под переменную `a`. Все совершенно единообразно.

Выделение памяти в таких примерах никоим образом не зависит правой части данного объявления, т.е. `= 5` никак не влияет на размер выделяемой памяти.

А затем, когда память уже выделена, значение `5` используется в качестве инициализатора для нового объекта. Как именно оно используется - зависит от конкретного типа. В первом случае оно просто заносится в переменную `var`. А что произойдет во втором случае уже зависит от деталей типа `Class`. Инициализация в С++ - процесс, описываемый целым набором весьма запутанных правил.